# No module named X even though I know it is installed

Tags: python, python-import

I am trying to access a fairly simple python package via pip from [here](https://pypi.org/project/inflect/) but am running into an error when I try and import. As usual, I have run `pip install inflect` and have confirmed that it is installed correctly. I then try to import in Spyder via `import inflect` but receive an error message stating: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'inflect'`

I have used this package on a different PC recently without issue. However, when I try to import on a new desktop I get the error mentioned above.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand correctly. Have you `pip` installed the package on the new PC?

Comment: Sorry for lack of clarity - yes, I used pip to install the package on the new PC.

Comment: You may have different versions of Python on your system and `pip` used version 1 for the installation and you try to run the code with version 2.

Comment: Does *Spyder* use the. same installation of Python as `pip` in the console? Does the package work when you run `python` in the console and import it there?

Comment: @millimoose running the package in the console does work as expected yes. I have no idea how I would have gone about using different installations. How do I go about correcting this so that it works in Spyder?

Comment: I don't really use Spyder, but in general when using an IDE, I'd lean on the IDE first. Doesn't Spyder have an UI to install packages; or better yet, a way to manage projects and add packages to them? Add `inflect` there, probably going to be easier than to reconcile multiple Python installs.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @millimoose. I've done as you suggested and it's now working.

Comment: Last time I faffed with Anaconda I think they had their own environment management mechanism, which Spyder should support seeing as it seems they're part of Anaconda? So the mental model would be something like: each project has its own Python environment, and you install libraries into that environment.

Answer (score 0):

when you are installing the library you can see the directory where it has been installed. Copy that dir and run the following:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "path/to/your/inflect")
import inflect
```

Comment: counterpoint: please don't

this sounds like a very bad practice if you're going to shove code anywhere near production - just use correct package management

Comment: And this approach is bound to crash if there are different versions of Python like 3.6 and 3.8.